# I cant figure out how to get a users input for the package selected to print at the end of the program when i call it

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program for someone to choose a ticket package to a baseball game and add which seat and how many seats they want. i am having my problem getting the answer they selected to print later in program. I have tried moving my if statements but it still doesn't seem to work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Proj2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner S = new Scanner (System.in);
    double TAX = .0625;
    char letter = 'Y';
    char letter2 = 'N';
    int Num = 1;
    int Num2 = 2;

    System.out.println("*** Welcome to the Kansas City Royals 2020 Season Ticketing Application ***" );
    System.out.println("                (Application developed by Tucker Deaton)");
    System.out.println("                            ----CROWNED KC!-----");
    System.out.println("Please select one of the Season Ticket Plans listed below:");
    System.out.println("1) Full Season Plan (tickets to all 81 regular season games!)" );
    System.out.println("2) Half Season plan (tickets to 40 regular season games)");
    System.out.println("3) Quarter Season Plan(tickets to 20 regular season games)");

    System.out.print("      Selection: ");
    int Selection = S.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please select one of the Seating Options listed below:");
    System.out.println("               Seating          Per Game");
    System.out.println("       1) BATS Crown Club Seats     $235");
    System.out.println("       2) Diamond CLub Box           $95");
    System.out.println("       3) Dugout box                 $51");
    System.out.println("       4) Dugout Plaza               $40");
    System.out.println("       5) Field Box                  $36");
    System.out.println("       6) Field Plaza                $28");
    System.out.println("       7) Outfield Box               $26");
    System.out.println("       8) Hy-Vee Box                 $16");

    System.out.print("          Selection: ");
    int selection = S.nextInt();

    System.out.print("        How many seats would you like to purchase?");
    int seats = S.nextInt();

    System.out.println("A single parking pass is available for purchase at a discounted rate of $8 per game (regularly $10).");
    System.out.println("(You will be charged for all games of a given package.)");
    System.out.print("Would you like to include Parking?(Y or N):");
    String parking = S.next();

    if (Selection == 1){
        System.out.println("Full Season Plan (tickets to all 81 regular season games!");
    }
    else if (Selection == 2){
        S.nextLine();
    }
    else if (Selection == 3){
        S.nextLine();
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid choice");

    if (letter == 'Y') {                    
        System.out.println("You purchased " + Selection);// where i want to print the answer the user chose for there package.
    }
    else if (letter2 == 'N'){
        System.out.println("Y");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't name any variables with a capital letter (Selection).  This leads to confusion with class names, which should start with a capital letter.  It's less confusing to name your variables using camelCase (planSelection, seatSelection).

Comment: Use local variables to hold what the User has selected or better yet, create and use a Season Tickets class.